# Req to Reopen "Working with people that have different views in geopolitics"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Working with people that have different views in geopolitics](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/133182/working-with-people-that-have-different-views-in-geopolitics)

This is not opinion based, and multinationals such as the one I work for are constantly handling this sticky situation with China.  There are established protocols and ways of handling it delicately, and has been done as such for decades now.

This should not have been closed, and should be reopened.

Comment: I voted to reopen. It's done.

Comment: Heh, you beat me for one second @JoeStrazzere

Comment: @DarkCygnus - as I try to explain to my grandchildren - not everything is a competition! ;-)  We still have a sad bunch of close-happy folks here, unfortunately.

Comment: it's not competition as the ultimate goal is to help :) I mentioned it because I casted my "vote" (which technically was the 6th) but it said "the post is already open"... something I have never seen before

Comment: @JoeStrazzere this one kind of shocked me, as the financial companies have been struggling with this for decades now

Comment: @RichardU - I'm no longer shocked by frantic close voting. Just disappointed I guess. Always happy to vote to reopen most questions.

Comment: @RichardU "Dragon Poker" made me laugh

Comment: It was definitely a great question for curious people. More and more workplaces are having both TW immigrants and mainlanders working together. Although I think @RichardU has overstated the sensitivity of the issue quite a bit, it's definitely non-trivial, and there are easy ways to avoid inviting conflict.

Answer (score 6):

Agreed.. it's totally valid (and a good, useful question IMO) - voted to reopen.